# IntelliJ mavenLocal Warning in Grails BuildConfig

Tags: grails, groovy

This warning started showing in IntelliJ :
'mavenLocal' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.config.RepositoriesConfigurer' cannot be applied to '()'

Here's the relevant snippet from BuildConfig.groovy.

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenRepo "https://mycompany.artifactoryonline.com/mycompany/repo"
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Environment:
OSX 10.6.8
Grails 2.0.3
IntelliJ 11.1.2

Comment: Does mavenLocal() require a a path of some sort?  How else does it know where to find the local maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mavenLocal method in RepositoriesConfigurer is defined like this:

```
void mavenLocal(String repoPath) {
    ...
}
```

So yes, mavenLocal expects a path, but is happy with getting null, which means to use the default repository path (.m2/repository under users home directory).

As I understand it, mavenLocal() resolves to calling mavenLocal(null) in this case.

mavenLocal should probably be changed to

```
void mavenLocal(String repoPath = null) {
    ...
}
```

to make it more obvious that the repoPath is optional, and get rid of the warning in IntelliJ

Comment: I changed the code to - mavenLocal(null) - and the error disappeared. Thanks!

Comment: I just got a pull request accepted with a fix for this. Starting from Grails 2.2, mavenLocal() will no longer cause a warning in IntelliJ. https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/241